Is the 'Quincey's moat' referenced in Edmund Blunden's 'Almswomen' a real place?
Edmund Blunden's poem 'Almswomen' begins:

At Quincey's moat the squandering village ends,

Does 'Quincey's moat' refer to a real place?
The only notable Quincey I know of is Thomas De Quincey, the famous opium addict. I don't believe he owned or built any earthworks. Anyone care to prove me wrong?
Looking at placenames is a bit more promising: there are several villages called Quincey. The problem here, though, is that all these villages are in France, whereas certain details in the rest of the poem, such as the names of local flora and fauna, strongly suggest an English setting:

They gloat upon their steepling hollyhocks,
Bee's balsams, feathery southernwood, and stocks,
Fiery dragon's-mouths, great mallow leaves
For salves, and lemon-plants in bushy sheaves,
Shagged Esau's-hands with five green finger-tips.
Such old sweet names are ever on their lips.

Does anyone have any ideas for where this 'Quincey's moat' might be?

There's a town in Massachusetts called Quincy, (pronounced quinzy) which is probably a different spelling of the same name.

@PeterShor I appreciate the suggestion, but I think that's a bit of a stretch. The poem clearly describes a sleepy rural village, which, even in the poet's day, Quincy, MA was not.

I completely agree ... this poem is clearly set in England. But Quincy, MA, was named after Colonel John Quincy, so presumably the surname Quincy is not that uncommon.

The Gazetteer of British Place Names has no entry for "Quincey." Neither does Wikipedia's list of country houses in the UK. Web searches for "Quincey's moat" result only in links to Blunden's poem. It seems likely, therefore, that the name is fictional.
Blunden spent part of his childhood in Yalding, Kent. Its Wikipedia page claims that "the village inspired more than fifty of his poems," and has a footnote linking to the Dictionary of National Biography's entry on Blunden. I am, alas, unable to view that page as it is paywalled. However, a post by kerry.brown01 on kentliterature.com says:

Through much of his life, the poet and critic Edmund Blunden (1896–1974) produced work which was informed, and often haunted, by the memory of his childhood in the village of Yalding, near Maidstone.

The article does mention this particular poem:

In all, Blunden spent less than a decade of his life in Yalding. And yet, the memory of that period recurs in work he produced into the 1950s. This was not just a matter of describing the physical landscape. Blunden was also careful in capturing some of the figures he knew – not so much their language, and voices, but at least the meaning of their characters. "Almswomen" from 1920 combines these, with its very specific reference to "Quincey’s Moat" — possibly the large house now named as Wardes Moat', and the two old dames living close by who "cling as close as any trueloves in the spring."  "All things they have in common being so poor," the poem continues, "And their one fear, Death’s shadow at the door."
Blunden had perhaps been promoted [sic; perhaps "prompted" is meant?] to adopt such a nostalgic, commemorative tone as much by the way his own life had moved on from the somewhat enclosed and protected nature of his infant existence in Yalding as by the devastating impact of the War.
kerry.brown01. "Edmund Blunden and the Memory of Yalding." 20 April 2023. Accessed at kentliterature.com 14 July 2024.

Yalding's almshouse is still extant and is now a heritage monument. The webpage of the Kent government says:

The Almshouses in Yalding were built in 1847 for 6 single women of the village and are still in use.
"Exploring Kent's Past: Almshouses, Yalding." Accessed at webapps.kent.gov.uk 14 July 2024.

These almshouses are located on a small street called Windmill Path that is off Blunden Lane. Apple Maps does have a bird's eye view of the street, and Wikimedia this photograph of the almshouses:

By Nigel Chadwick. CC BY-SA 2.0. Wikimedia Commons. Retrieved 14 July 2024.
The house named Wardes Moat is indeed at the edge of the village.

What a rich, specific answer to such a small, obscure question. Thank you.

yer welcome. Glad you liked it!

The entry for Blunden in the 2004 edition of the ODNB is in volume 6, pages 341–343. It does not substantiate the "more than fifty of his poems" claim in Wikipedia: the only mention of Yalding is, "When Edmund was four the family moved to Yalding in Kent, where he discovered the love of rural life and natural history that pervaded his whole career as a writer."
